# Vue router picking up window.open on production only

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, window.open

I'm trying to open a different tab for users with window.open

```
   window.open(
     'https:/example.com/'+urlParameters,
     '_blank'
   );
```

This works perfectly on development (localhost).

When running a build on production it looks like the vue router is interfering.. the browser opens a new tab to:

https://siteurlofvueproject.nl/example.com/?urlparameters

Is there a way to bypass the vue router for window.open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try with simple link:

```
<a :href="'https:/example.com/' + urlParameters" target="_blank">outside link</a>
```

Comment: thanks, but this is the opposite of what i need :).  (second method, i cant use routerlink) I need to open a separate url completely outside of the vue project. With your code i get:http://localhost:8080/https:/example.com/

Comment: @Bas Broens hey mate, sorry my bad , I misunderstood your questions, take a look at updated answer pls :)

Comment: changed the code to <v-btn :href="url" target="_blank"></btn> following your advise. Now its working.. however still weird the vue router is overruling window.open

Comment: @BasBroens A router can't overrule anything, it should work as expected if url is correct. In your example the protocol is wrong. It's a bad idea to use window.open without a good reason because it will be blocked by popup blockers